# Rails: "except" vs "slice" to take out certain parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a class instance with one particular key extracted out and save for later

consider this is the type of param:

```
Parameters: {"p1": "foo", "p2": "bar", "p3":"param that i want to extract" >
```

I would do something like:

```
@my_class = MyClass.new(whiteList_function.except(:p3))
```

or something like

```
@my_class = MyClass.new(whiteList_function)
@my_class_key = @my_class.slice(:p3)
```

My whiteList_function:

```
def whiteList_function
    params.require(:my_class).permit(:p1,:p2,p3)
end
```

My concern is that, I have searched on SO and some have mentioned the security risk of using `except`.

So my question is, in this particular usage(take out certain key and use them for later), should I use `except` or `slice`?

Comment: Your two snippets do different things.  For example, in the first one you do nothing with `p3`. And in the second one, `MyClass.new` receives `p3` along with others.

Comment: If you want to *take out certain key and use it later* then you might want to `delete(:that_key)` from the source hash and store it in a separate variable *before* calling `MyClass.new(some_h)`. Unless you want to keep the source hash the same all the way, then `except` is your friend.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Doesn't "slice" do the same thing as "delete"?

Comment: No, `slice` does not remove the key/value pair from the hash, `delete` does: `{ a: 1, b: 2 }.tap { |h| h.slice(:a) }.key?(:a)` returns `true` but `{ a: 1, b: 2 }.tap { |h| h.delete(:a) }.key?(:a)` returns `false`

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks for the input. I see what I wanted to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `except` with parameter hashes is dangerous because you're saying "allow any parameter other than this one" so it opens your model up to mass-assignment attacks.

Unless I'm not thinking of another attack vector you should be fine, because you're filtering your acceptable parameter hash with [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in your `whiteList_function`. So, you're fine further filtering that hash with either `slice` or `except`, whichever is more appealing to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Rails user and maybe I misunderstand your question but in plain Ruby here is what I would do

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :params
  def initialize params
    @params = whiteList_function params
  end
  def whiteList_function params
    whiteList = [:p1, :p2]
    params.select{|key| whiteList.include? key }
  end
end

MyClass.new({"p1": "foo", "p2": "bar", "p3":"param that i want to extract"})
# #<MyClass:0x00000002802a58 @params={:p1=>"foo", :p2=>"bar"}>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to omit the `p3` key/value pair only for a specific context but still keep it as whitelisted in other contexts (to be confirmed though)